# How to implement custom initialiser method of uiviewController in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, init

How to implement the below objective-c init method in swift

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withName:(NSString *)name {
    if (self = [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.name = name;
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/08/initializing-view-controllers-in-swift.html

Comment: @TonyMkenu I got something from the link.I just want to know is it possible to send parameters like or should i follow some other way.

Comment: required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    foo = "some string"
    bar = 9001
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be this:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?, name:String!)
{
      self.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil);

        self.name = name;
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg.png"));
}
```

You may have to implement required initializers if you get an error, but should not be needed if you use a later version than Beta5:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: where the sending of "name" parameter

Comment: Sorry, forgot that one. I added a it as parameter. But, as in ObjC, now it is not a standard initializer anymore.

Comment: then how to call this method from a another viewController. I mean how to pass data from one controller to another controller.

Comment: Same way as you would do it in ObjC, you define the function in your header and use it instead of the standard initializers.